# Get post_meta of one post type who is different of display post

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I'm looking for to get "get_post_meta" from a post type which is different of the display post ?
here is my code , but this display the post_meta of all posts in the post type !
I think it could be compare the posts who have the same slug (post_name) , but I don't know how to do !

```
<?php  $sectionscontact = new WP_query(array('post_type' => 'sections-contact', 'post_count'=>1));if ($sectionscontact->have_posts()): while ( $sectionscontact->have_posts() ) : $sectionscontact->the_post(); $telephone_meta_empty = get_post_meta(451,'telephone', true);
        if ( ! empty ( $telephone_meta_empty ) ) { ?>
            <div class="tp_titre_bloc" style="border-right:1px solid #999999;"> Téléphone</div>
                    <div class="tp_content_bloc">
                                <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'telephone', true); ?>
                </div>
    <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done here is to tidy it up for you.

Also, it displays the post_meta for everything in this post type because you're using `post_count` as opposed to `posts_per_page`, which is the correct term to display some certain amount of posts in one query.

So, Instead of this:

```
<?php  
    $sectionscontact = new WP_query( array(
    'post_type' => 'sections-contact', 
    'post_count' => 1
    ));

    if ($sectionscontact->have_posts()):
    while ( $sectionscontact->have_posts() ) : 
    $sectionscontact->the_post(); 

    $telephone_meta_empty = get_post_meta(451,'telephone', true);
    if ( ! empty ( $telephone_meta_empty ) ) { ?>
    <div class="tp_titre_bloc" style="border-right:1px solid #999999;">Téléphone</div>
    <div class="tp_content_bloc">
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'telephone', true); ?>
    </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

You want this:

```
<?php  
    $sectionscontact = new WP_query( array(
    'post_type' => 'sections-contact', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1 //changed post_count to posts_per_page
    ));

    if ($sectionscontact->have_posts()):
    while ( $sectionscontact->have_posts() ) : 
    $sectionscontact->the_post(); 

    $telephone_meta_empty = get_post_meta(451,'telephone', true);
    if ( ! empty ( $telephone_meta_empty ) ) { ?>
    <div class="tp_titre_bloc" style="border-right:1px solid #999999;">Téléphone</div>
    <div class="tp_content_bloc">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'telephone', true); // changed get_the_id() to $post->ID?>
    </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Let me know if that helps.

More info on WP_Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Thanks.